# Simplest way to use windows software on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I am trying to use windows software (games mostly) on my Chromebook (acer c720). On our old Chromebook, I downloaded chrUbuntu, booted chrUbuntu, then installed wine. chrUbuntu no longer works, so I'm not sure how to proceed. I would also like to avoid using a windows operating system if possible.

Comment: The type of games supported by Wine would be rather restricted, but I'm sure you know that. If you can't install Linux even with developer mode turned on then you're out of luck.

Comment: i can install it thrue crouton but i dont know what crouton compatible OS'es  can run wine

Comment: You can install Wine on both Ubuntu and Debian which crouton officially supports.

Comment: I use various remote desktops software. I pay for LogMeIn, but on my Chromebook, Chrome Remote Desktop is FAST! It's like I'm on my Windows box when I'm on my Chromebook. My home box and my Chromebook are both 1920x1080, so it's nice. My home box is dual-monitor and I can use both on my Chromebook. Because Chromebooks can use any mouse-- my Chromebook is my laptop. Do you mean native games? No. The Chromebook is cheap because ChromeOS doesn't require much hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research, and discovered it would be hard to find a distro that is not compatible. Wine is pretty much universal. 
https://www.winehq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You also cannot install a windows os on a chromebook so you wont have to worry about using a windows os if you plan on keeping that chromebook.

Comment: Not entirely correct. Windows can successfully be installed on certain Chromebook models, but there's no Windows driver so far for the Google i2c device and so the touchpad and keyboard won't work.